# How to add a column where the value increases based upon another column

Tags: mysql

I have a table like below. I want to add a column named `Number` that should increase based upon `Cluster` and `DriveNumber` (or `Cluster` + `Date` + `DriveNumber`:

```
Cluster         Cluster + Sub-cluster   DriveNumbe  Date
GCR_OPT_WELAC01 GCR_OPT_WELAC01         1+2         12/9/2015
GCR_OPT_WELAC01 GCR_OPT_WELAC01         1+2         12/9/2015
GCR_OPT_WELAC01 GCR_OPT_WELAC01         1+2         1/4/2016
GCR_OPT_WELAC01 GCR_OPT_WELAC01         1+2         1/4/2016
L700_NEDCC41    L700_NEDCC41            1+2+3       12/9/2015
L700_NEDCC41    L700_NEDCC41            1+2+3       16/11/2015
L700_NEDCC41    L700_NEDCC41            1+2+3       09/12/2016
```

The desired output is:

```
Cluster         Cluster + Sub-cluster   DriveNumbe  Date        Number
GCR_OPT_WELAC01 GCR_OPT_WELAC01         1+2         12/9/2015   1
GCR_OPT_WELAC01 GCR_OPT_WELAC01         1+2         12/9/2015   1
GCR_OPT_WELAC01 GCR_OPT_WELAC01         1+2         1/4/2016    2
GCR_OPT_WELAC01 GCR_OPT_WELAC01         1+2         1/4/2016    2
L700_NEDCC41    L700_NEDCC41            1+2+3       12/9/2015   1
L700_NEDCC41    L700_NEDCC41            1+2+3       16/11/2015  2
L700_NEDCC41    L700_NEDCC41            1+2+3       09/12/2016  2
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the ANSI SQL window function `dense_rank()`:

```
select t.*,
       dense_rank() over (partition by cluster, drivenumber order by date) as number
from t;
```

MySQL doesn't support these functions.  Instead, you can do:

```
select t.*,
       (select count(distinct t2.date)
        from t t2
        where t2.cluster = t.cluster and t2.drivenumber = t.drivenumber and
              t2.date <= t.date
       ) as number
from t;
```

Comment: is the same function is available in mysql

Comment: Thanks i am getting the desired result.

Comment: Same result can be achieved by below query

Answer (score 0):

```
set @pk1 ='';
set @rn1 =1;
set @sal ='';
set @val =1;

SELECT  dept_id,
    salary,
    denseRank
FROM
(
 SELECT  dept_id,
      salary,
      @rn1 := if(@pk1=dept_id, if(@sal=salary, @rn1, @rn1+@val),1) as        denseRank,
      @val := if(@pk1=dept_id, if(@sal=salary, @val+1, 1),1) as value,
      @pk1 := dept_id,
      @sal := salary     
  FROM
(
  SELECT  dept_id,
        salary
FROM    emp
ORDER BY dept_id,salary
) A 
) B;
```

Comment: This is dangerous code.  It assumes that the expressions in a `select` are evaluated in order.  This is not only not guaranteed, but MySQL actually does evaluate the expressions out-of-order (sometimes).